# Update User with propertyValues using SimpleMembershipAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

i'm creating my custom values with this function

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount( 
model.UserName, 
model.Password,
propertyValues: new
{
  web_UserNr= model.web_UserNr,
  web_company= model.company,
  web_Person= model.web_Person,
  web_Status= model.web_Status,
  ….
});
```

All the User data is stored in the usertable.

But I didn’t find a way how to update the user
Using `Membership.UpdateUser` I cound not find a way to pass the propertyvalues
Also I didn’t find a way how to read these propertyvalues (beside direct from the database)
Is there a function to update and retrieve these values?
Thx!